# How to specify the smart contract entry point in eztz call?

Tags: smart-contracts, eztz

I want to call a smart contract with eztz:

```
eztz.contract.send(contract,from, keys, amoun, params, gasLimit,storageLimit)
```

How to specify the entry point, my smart contract has multiple entry points :

```
   parameter
    (or :_entries
      (int %_Liq_entry_create)
      (int %_Liq_entry_main))
    ;
storage
    (list
      int)
    ;
code
    {
      DUP ;
      DIP
        {
          CDR @storage_slash_1 ;
        }
        ;
      CAR @parameter_slash_2 ;
      DUP @parameter ;
      IF_LEFT
        {
          RENAME @parameter_slash_3
            ;
          DUUUP @storage ;
          NIL
            operation
            ;
          PAIR ;
          DIP
            {
              DROP ;
            }
            ;
        }
        {
          RENAME @parameter_slash_5
            ;
          DUUUP @storage ;
          NIL
            operation
            ;
          PAIR ;
          DIP
            {
              DROP ;
            }
            ;
        }
        ;
      DIP
        {
          DROP ;
          DROP ;
        }
        ;
    }
    ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Michelson doesn't support multiple entry points right now. Liquidity uses unions (or type variables) to make up for this. A union has a Left and Right side, but can also be nested.

Let's analyse the parameter of the script provided:

```
parameter
    (or :_entries
      (int %_Liq_entry_create)  <-- Left Side
      (int %_Liq_entry_main))   <-- Right Side
    ;
```

So, to call the first entry point, you would use the following in eztz:

```
eztz.contract.send(contract,from, keys, amoun, "(Left 1)", gasLimit,storageLimit)
```

To access the second entry point, you would use:

```
eztz.contract.send(contract,from, keys, amoun, "(Right 1)", gasLimit,storageLimit)
```

This is not specific to eztz, but applies to calling smart contracts from all wallets and even the tezos-client.